# Xcode11 Swift5 framework does not contain header for simulators, only for arm64 and armv7a

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode11, swift5

Xcode11 Swift5 framework does not contain header for simulators, only for arm64 and armv7a.
Hence, I am unable to use the framework to run on the simulator 11.x and 12.x simulators.

Examination of the Swift5 framework header shows following structure:

```
#if 0
#elif defined(__arm64__) && __arm64__
// Generated by Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)

....
....
....

#elif defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__) && __ARM_ARCH_7A__
// Generated by Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)

....
....
....

#endif
```

It is evident from above that the framework has no headers matching simulator architecture.

How do I package simulator headers to the framework?

Comment: XCode build your framework depends on the device you choose, you have to combine simulator and device slices into a fat framework in order to have it works for both

Answer (score 0):

Header are generated during the build. I assume that you try to use a fat framework created with lipo.

During the build you generate the Header, Info.plist, modules  and binaries for each.

So at the step where you combine simulator files and devices files, you can create a header that regroup header for simulator and for device.
Don't forget to add a `if` for the simulator's one, otherwise it will not compile. 
sh script :

```
# if use only with simulator
echo '#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR' > build/arch/universal/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h

# simulator header 
cat build/arch/x86/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h >> build/arch/universal/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h

# end of if
echo '#endif' >> build/arch/universal/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h

# device header
cat build/arch/arm/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h >> build/arch/universal/Framework.framework/Headers/Framework-Swift.h
```

To answer your question, you just have to concat both and add a if to choose the correct for each case.

Comment: can you please explain steps with narration and screenshots please